How to access an element on a web page by XPath using the nodriver library in Python?
I tried to write a wait_for_xpath function, but I'm unable to create an Element class for interacting with an element on the web page using the dom.py module.
Here's the code:
async def wait_for_xpath(
        xpath: str,
        tab: Tab,
        timeout: int = 10
) -> Element:
    await tab.send(cdp.dom.enable())
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    now = loop.time()
    search_id, count = await tab.send(cdp.dom.perform_search(query=xpath))
    while count == 0:
        if loop.time() - now >= timeout:
            raise TimeoutError(f"Timeout waiting for xpath: {xpath}")
        await tab.sleep(0.5)
        search_id, count = await tab.send(cdp.dom.perform_search(query=xpath))
    node_id = await tab.send(cdp.dom.push_node_by_path_to_frontend(xpath))
    node = await tab.send(cdp.dom.describe_node(node_id))
    return Element(node, tab, node)

I would appreciate your help in advance!
I tried to implement a function that is not available in the nodriver library, but I couldn't succeed.

You can just use the built-in tab.find(xpath) function.
For example:
create_account = await tab.find("/html/body/div/p[2]/a")
await create_account.click()

